How to configure Renovate to keep peer and dev dependencies matched?
I have a monorepo in which I'm writing library packages that depend on peer dependencies.
I have some of those peer dependencies also installed in my root package, and Renovate is trying to upgrade the development dependency in the library packages, and I am getting upgrade suggestions like these:
  {
    "devDependencies": {
-     "eslint": "9.0.0"
+     "eslint": "9.3.0"
    },
    "peerDependencies": {
      "eslint": "^9.0.0"
    }
  }

I'd like to configure Renovate to prevent updating the development dependency of eslint, but instead keep it pinned to the peer version for library packages, and generally wouldn't want to widen my peers, unless there is a major release.
I'm curious if there's some kind of way that I can configure Renovate easily for all the library packages, without having to provide a lot of individual configurations.

Isn't this the default behaviour? I believe Renovate will open a single PR grouping updates to both lines as they refer to the same dependency. Or maybe I didn't understand what you're looking for vs. what you get currently.

@GaëlJ I've expanded the question a bit to clarify what's happening now and what I'd rather like.
